# PHP / Ajax: How to initiate session after successful login (rest of code working)

Tags: php, ajax, session, session-variables, session-cookies

I am new to PHP and hope someone can help me with the following.

I am working on setting up a login page where I am using an onclick event on a button to verify the email and password ("pass") that the user entered (checking if email exists and if password matches).

So far everything works as intended but I couldn't figure out the following: 
I start a session in my header file as below. Now when I verified a user's email and password ("`password correct`") **I would like to pass two variables to this session so that on other pages I can see the user is already logged in**. Therefore I wanted to pass a variable "`login`" as "`loggedIn`" and the user's email address as "`username`".

Can someone tell me how I can realise this here ?
Can I just do this on the ajax.php page when I already verified the user ?

**How the session is being started in my header:**

```
session_start();
```

**The Ajax call to verify the user (in jQuery):**

```
$.ajax({        
    type: "post",   
    url: "ajax.php",
    cache: "false",
    data: {
        node: 'loginUser',
        email: email,
        pass: pass
    },
    success: function(data){
        if(data == 'Password correct'){
            // redirect to index page
            window.location.href = baseURL + '/index.php?lang=' + selectedLang
        }else{
            alert(data);
        }
    },
    error: function(){
    }
});
```

**The part on the ajax.php page that verifies the user with the input from the Ajax:**

```
case "loginUser":
    // login user
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $pass = $_POST["pass"]; 

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT pw FROM Users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();          
    if(!$result || !$result->num_rows){
        echo "Email has not been registered yet";
    }else{      
        $passHashed = $result->fetch_assoc();
        if(password_verify($pass, $passHashed["pw"])){
            echo "Password correct";
        }else{
            echo "Password incorrect";
        }
    }
    break;
```

Many thanks in advance for any help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `ajax.php` do like this:-

```
<?php
session_start(); // this must be first line
case "loginUser":
    // login user
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $pass = $_POST["pass"]; 

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT pw FROM Users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();          
    if(!$result || !$result->num_rows){
        echo "Email has not been registered yet";
    }else{      
        $passHashed = $result->fetch_assoc();
        if(password_verify($pass, $passHashed["pw"])){
            $_SESSION['User']['login'] = 'loggedIn'; // assignment 
            $_SESSION['User']['username'] = $email;  // assignment
            echo "Password correct";
        }else{
            echo "Password incorrect";
        }
    }
    break;
```

And on any other php page:-

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "<pre/>";print_r($_SESSION['User']);
// rest code
?>
```

Comment: This is awesome - thanks a lot ! I like the approach with the User.

Comment: I am sorry, just saw one thing: Regarding the pre tag that you use, is there no need to open the tag before ? Sorry if that's a beginner question.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried setting a session variable after your statement

```
$passHashed = $result->fetch_assoc();
if(password_verify($pass, $passHashed["pw"])){
    echo "Password correct";
    //set session loggedIn = variable login
    $_SESSION["loggedIn"]= true;
    //set user to
    $_SESSION["username"]= $email;
} else {...}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, no I haven't. I have never used sessions before so I was a bit stuck here. So I can do this directly on the ajax.php page ?

Comment: @TaneMahuta no problem! You can view the detailed docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php there is quite a few examples

Comment: The link and info you provided is really good and definitely helps a lot. The answer from Anant is just a bit more detailed and seems to work perfect for what I need so I will accept his answer but voted yours up, hope that's ok. Thanks again for your help !